# Regexp containing string and not containing another

Tags: regex

I have some problems filtering with regexp.

I have a log with multiple entries like:

```
2015-09-03 03:35:05,074  WARN  [repo.sync.SyncTrackerComponent]  missing event: CREATE
```

`2015-09-04 03:35:05,074  ERROR [repo.sync.SyncTrackerComponent] Unable to pull 
 2015-09-04 03:35:05,074  WARN  [repo.sync.SyncTrackerComponent]  missing event: CREATE`

```
2015-09-04 11:21:58,638  ERROR [repo.jscript.ScriptLogger]   Cost center review Id 473805
2015-09-04 14:02:16,917  ERROR [repo.jscript.ScriptLogger]  Tarea actual - GBS Review
```

i use a regular expresion  in notepad++  to filter errors by an expeficic day(i.e. errors today) `2015-09-04.*ERROR` would output:

```
2015-09-04 03:35:05,074  ERROR [repo.sync.SyncTrackerComponent] Unable to pull
2015-09-04 11:21:58,638  ERROR [repo.jscript.ScriptLogger]   Cost center review Id 473805
2015-09-04 14:02:16,917  ERROR [repo.jscript.ScriptLogger]  Tarea actual - GBS Review
```

I would like to filter too for example the errors that doesnt contain a certain description.Im trying to use  `2015-09-04.*ERROR.*(?!.*Unable to pull)` willing to have this output:

```
2015-09-04 11:21:58,638  ERROR [repo.jscript.ScriptLogger]   Cost center review Id 473805
2015-09-04 14:02:16,917  ERROR [repo.jscript.ScriptLogger]  Tarea actual - GBS Review
```

But it doesnt work. What`s wrong with the negative lookup?

Comment: Try `^(?!.*Unable to pull)2015-09-04.*ERROR.*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (which @stribizhev hinted at in the comments) is that you are matching `.*` after `ERROR`, which means it matches everything before your negative lookahead is able to (un)match anything.

```
2015-09-04.*ERROR.*(?!.*Unable to pull)
                /|\
                 |
               problem
```

If you put the negative lookahead ahead of the rest of your match, it should work.

```
2015-09-04.*ERROR(?!.*Unable to pull).*
```

## [See Demo](http://rubular.com/r/5yfutVRrev)

Comment: the actual regexp that finally worked for me is ^(?!.*Unable to pull.*)2015-09-04.*ERROR.*
Thanks